# Improving Python List Comprehension to Eliminate Nested Arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a list comprehension, that improves upon one I already have.

I have a list of numbers representing the lengths of a month.

```
months = [35, 28, 28, 35, 28, 28, 35, 28, 28, 35, 28, 28]
```

I want to expand this array into an array with a length of the full year, and every value in that array representing which week that day (index) falls into.

Currently I am doing this with two list comprehensions.

```
weeks = [w for w in range(sum(months)) if w % 7 == 0]
weeks_expanded = [day for week in [[d + 1] * 7 for d in range(len(weeks))] for day in week]
```

I wanted to know how I could add something to the new list 7 times without making it an array of length 7. I'm trying to get rid of the added step of flattening my inner list comprehension in weeks_expanded. `[[d + 1] * 7 for d in range(len(weeks))]`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's an interesting deviation from the Gregorian calendar months; what calendar system is this?

Comment: `weeks` can be defined as `range(0, sum(months), 7)`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It's called a 4-5-4 calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically generating a sequence of every 7th number for the `weeks` sequence, up to the year-total number of days, so this works too:

```
weeks = range(0, sum(months), 7)
```

`weeks_expanded` list is just a sequence of repeated integers, starting at 1, each repeated 7 times, up to and including `sum(months) // 7`, so you could just do this:

```
weeks_expanded = [wn for wn in range(1, (sum(months) // 7) + 1) for __ in range(7)]
```

This uses a nested loop in the list comprehension, that just iterates 7 times. You could also use the [`itertools.product()` iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to flatten this to a single loop:

```
from itertools import product

weeks_expanded = [wn for wn, __ in product(range(1, (sum(months) // 7) + 1), (None,) * 7)]
```

This uses a tuple of 7 `None` references to add the repetition, the loop then ignores those values.

Neither version needs `weeks` to exist.